# draw path with translucent (semi-transparent) band

Tags: android, path, transparency, draw

[image]
How can i draw path with translucent (semi-transparent) band on canvas (method onDraw in my custom View)? I draw path line by bezier curve (method path.quadTo), but i want to around the line was illuminated translucent band?
I tried several approaches:

1. Try draw path by paint with semi-transparent color 0x8800ff00.
2. Try use paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(semi-transparent background image)) and draw path by this paint;

But they did not help. There was no effect of translucency.

Comment: I think answer to the question below may help people trying to find a solution to this problem (it did work for me): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281783/dynamically-generated-line-with-glow-effective

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you first draw the curve using a `Paint` with a much bigger `StrokeWidth` and a transparent color (this being the glow), then draw your first curve on top of it?

Comment: I tried this approach, but it didn't help me. Line with biggest stroke width and semi-transparent color was without transparency.