# Dynamically generated line with glow effective

Tags: android, paint, touch-event

I want to draw line with glow effect like this 
[image: glow line]

The problem - i must generate this line in program in dependence on  user's interaction ( the form of line will be generated in `onTouchEvent` - `ACTION_MOVE` ).

Can i generate this effect without xml files or drawing premaid bitmap ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I imitate this effect in this way :

1. Draw line with [`BlurMaskFilter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlurMaskFilter.html);
2. Draw over it normal line.

I use Path class to generate line and save coordinates of `MOVE_ACTION` event to generate only part of path what i need.

Create 2 `Paint()`s:

```
_paintSimple = new Paint();
_paintSimple.setAntiAlias(true);
_paintSimple.setDither(true);
_paintSimple.setColor(Color.argb(248, 255, 255, 255));
_paintSimple.setStrokeWidth(20f);
_paintSimple.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
_paintSimple.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
_paintSimple.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

_paintBlur = new Paint();
_paintBlur.set(_paintSimple);
_paintBlur.setColor(Color.argb(235, 74, 138, 255));
_paintBlur.setStrokeWidth(30f);
_paintBlur.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
```

And draw twice my `Path()`:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, _paintBlur);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, _paintSimple);
}
```

Comment: what is **mPath** ?? 

i did new var. with same name 


    Path mPath  = new Path();

no Change !

Comment: mPath would be the path object that you use to build the line to draw. You can add points to the path (points where the user has touched) and then draw the path.

Comment: Be aware of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281404/android-blurmaskfilter-has-no-effect-in-canvas-drawoval-while-text-is-blurred

Comment: This works only when hardware acceleration is disabled, use `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` on your view to do so.

Comment: As @Tom said, the layerType must be set. This can also be achieved by setting android:layerType="software" in XML.

Comment: Perfect Answer.