# How to draw text with glow and neon effects on android canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

How can this be accomplished?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
paint = new Paint();

path=new Path();
path.moveTo(50, 50);
paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 25, 25, 255));
paint.setTextSize(70);
paint.setFakeBoldText(true);

paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.SOLID));
Typeface typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF,Typeface.BOLD);
paint.setTypeface(typeface);           

paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setDither(true);
paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
```

Comment: Edited for clarity; added missing tag

Comment: See the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281783/dynamically-generated-line-with-glow-effective